# FOR JNI experts, How Would I use JNI to call ReadProcessMemory? (Read memory from windows applications)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, readprocessmemory

I would like to know if theres a possibility to call C++ methods from java.

Pretty much I want to be able to read memory processes from java.

I know c++, but I Would like to use a higher lvl like java, but still be able to hack into processes memory.

Any clues?

[]'s

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) project, which lets you call any function exposed in a DLL, without writing any JNI code.

Comment: Hey there, I managed to find a nice example in here.. http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5155307
But its unclear to me, how to properly return the value of a given memory address.
I tried entering the memory address in there, and it returned some ascii trash